# Fonts emulating dot matrix printers

Tags: ocr, printing, font

I am looking for True Type fonts that render printed characters as those generated by needle, thermal or inkjet printers, of the industrial type. I mean real printer fonts with sizes like 5x7, 7x9 or larger (sometimes with width or height doubling). They are use to print expiry dates, lot codes...

I am not after fancy dot fonts that more or less mimic a printed style, as are found in specialized font sites for graphists.

Where can I find this ? (Alternatively to TTF, good quality images showing the entire fonts could do.)